# Why can't a select values not in double quotes from a json file in python programming

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
import json
f = open(r'C:\Users\Arun\Documents\Input.json',)
data = json.load(f)
json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"))
for i in data["notificationChannels"]:
 if i["enabled"] == "true":
        print(i)
```

But I can get the values if I use  if i["type"] == "BEAN": , Why can't I pull values which are not in double quotes

Sample Json File Content:

```
{
"notificationChannels": [
  {
     "type": "BEAN",
     "enabled": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the "json" library was build to read the value of `true` (without double quotes) as boolean `True`, so that the comparison to string "true" is wrong in the first place.

My suggestion to try:

```
...
if i["enabled"] == True:
...
```

Comment: if i["enabled"]:

This one is worked, Thank a lot!

Comment: Better to use the first option to prevent evaluating expressions that are not pure boolean as true

Comment: if i["enabled"] == True: this one worked as well, I was trying with lowercase earlier(true) :)
thanks again!